# Giving event’s function by variable

Tags: jquery

```
while (infoRepNames.length > 0) {
   infoRepName = infoRepNames.substr(0,8);
   $('.' + infoRepName).on('click', DMRep002).css({'font-size': '1em', 'font-weight': 900});
   infoRepNames = infoRepNames.substr(9);
}
```

This goes ok. In infoRepNames I have 0-to-n function-names out of “DMRep001” until DMRep999”separated by “;”.  Each time I take one function-name off and the above code works when there is only one name “DMRep002” in infoRepNames and I use the name “DMRep002” literally in the command.

However, when I replace the direct call for “DMRep002” by “infoRepName”, than I get the message from firebug: “Uncaught TypeError : Object DMRap002 has no method ‘apply’”.

To be clear: I changed the line

```
$('.' + infoRepName).on('click', DMRap002).css({'font-size': '1em', 'font-weight': 900});
```

into

```
$('.' + infoRepName).on('click', infoRepName).css({'font-size': '1em', 'font-weight': 900});
```

The functions are calls for different forms. I now have about 500 different forms in my situation.
Is there some way to handle the above dynamically with this amount of different functions?

Comment: It needs to be a function reference but `infoRepName` is a string.

Answer (score 0):

Store your functions in an object:

```
var funcs = {
  DMRep001 : function(){ ... },
  DMRep002 : function(){ ... },
  ...
  DMRep999 : function(){ ... }
};
```

then you can call them as:

```
$('.' + infoRepName).on('click', funcs[infoRepName]);
```

though I smell some antipattern in having all such different handlers.